# How to remove the margin added to the label in TextField that has prefixIcon when receiving focus?

Tags: flutter, material-design, flutter-layout

When the TextDield receives focus the label receives a margin in relation to the prefixIcon.

Current

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Objective:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```dart
Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
  child: TextFormField(
    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
    textInputAction: TextInputAction.continueAction,
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      alignLabelWithHint: true,
      prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.device_thermostat),
      labelText: "Temperature",
      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
      hintText: "Enter  temperature",
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: you want to add margin only when the textField is in focus??

Comment: No, I want the icon and the label to have the same left padding as in the second image  when in focus.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.device_thermostat),` with `prefix: Icon(Icons.device_thermostat),`. [Here](https://www.dartpad.dev/b6409e10de32b280b8938aa75364fa7b) is an example on DartPad with one field using `prefixIcon` and a second using `prefix`.